# How to override ansible_user on command line?

Tags: ansible

In `group_vars/all.yml` I defined a default remote user:

```
ansible_user: blackknight
```

But in some cases I like to override that on the command line:

`% ansible-playbook -u kingarthur test.yml`

`test.yml` is a simple debug playbook

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug: var=ansible_user
```

when executing it tells me `"ansible_user": "blackknight"`.

How should I change my variables or playbook to have a non-standard `ansible_user`, but still allow it to specify on the command line (so that the command line option takes precedences over my default in the variables)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/general_precedence.html#using-e-extra-variables-at-the-command-line):

> #### Using -e extra variables at the command line
>
> To override all other settings in all other categories, you can use
>   extra variables: `--extra-vars` or `-e` at the command line. Values
>   passed with `-e` are variables, not command-line options, and they
>   will override configuration settings, command-line options, and
>   playbook keywords as well as variables set elsewhere. For example,
>   this task will connect as `brian` not as `carol`:
>
> ```
> ansible -u carol -e 'ansible_user=brian' -a whoami all
> ```
>
> You must specify both the variable name and the value with
>   `--extra-vars`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Somehow, I missed that part, only reading the top of that page which said that command line takes precedence over variables. That is true for `-e` for not true for `-u`. Feels odd to me that these two options behave so differently. Must be an ansible quirk.

Comment: @MacFreek I think what they mean to say is that: options > variables (from inventory, etc.), but variables from `-e` > options > variables (from inventory, etc.). It's not specific to `-u`.

Comment: Indeed, being new to Ansible, I somehow expected all command line options to have equal precedence, but it seems that some command line options are more equal than others ;) (and now I learned about `-e`. I didn't look further when I discovered `-u`)

Comment: I should have read the documentation better.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable